# Python CLI and Import Module

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import

I'm trying to figure out how to set up a python "project" as both a CLI command and an import "object".
This probably has a simple answer(s), but I'm not as familiar with the technical terms so I'm not quite sure what I need to research.

What I would like to have:
`mytool` being a python "thing" (module/package?)
I can run `pip install -e /home/user/project/mytool/` (or whatever it needs to be)
Then I can use it in these two ways:

- use `mytool` as a CLI command:

```
   CLI usage: mytool string_input
   CLI output: result_string
```

- import mytool in a different python script and use it there:

```
    In other script usage:
    import mytool
    result_string = mytool.process_string(string_input)
```

This is my setup:

```
$ tree ./mytool/
./mytool/
├── __init__.py
├── setup.py
├── mytool
│   ├── mytool_helper.py
│   └── mytool.py
├── mytool.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── mytool_helper.py
└── mytool.py

2 directories, 12 files
```

I know I don't need mytool.py and mytool_helper.py in both folders, but this has been my rough trying to get something to work, before pruning. I've tried to pattern this from a couple of other python things, but I think I've just confused myself at this point.

I have also read `__init__.py` can be empty, but it might be what I'm looking for, this is the content of `__init__.py`:

```
from mytool.mytool import *
```

contents of `setup.py`:

```
"""
The setup module(?) for mytool
"""

# To use a consistent encoding
from os import path

# Always prefer setuptools over distutils
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

version = '0.0.2'

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__))

setup(
    name='mytool',
    version=version,

    description='Do stuff with a string',


    packages=find_packages(),
    py_modules=['mytool'],

    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3.10'
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'argparse',
        'pyyaml'
    ],
    extras_require={
    },
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mytool=mytool.mytool:main'
        ]
    }
)
```

contents of mytool.py (simplified):

```
import json
import argparse

from mytool.mytool_helper import HelperClass

# various string manipulation functions
#...

def process_string(in_string):
    result = HelperClass.parse_string(in_string)
    #  Do stuff with string
    return result.to_string()


def main():
    # This just gets the input via argparse
    input_string = _get_input_string()
    result_string = process_string(input_string)
    print(json.dumps(result_string, indent=4, default=str))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

The current behavior is:
`pip install -e /home/user/project/mytool/`

- CLI: `mytool string_to_process`
- In a script:

```
from mytool import mytool
result = mytool.process_string("string_to_process")
```

How do I fix and clean my project so I can just use below while still having the CLI functionality?

```
import mytool
result = mytool.process_string("string_to_process")
```

I don't need the helper directly "importable".

Answer (score 1):

Finally found a question that lead me to a solution, but I still welcome feedback and comments!

This question:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/243044
(they asked which is preferred)
asks about single python file distribution where you have a file `foo.py` which has an internal thing (function,class,etc) called `useful_thing`

They provide 2 file architectures so one could use `from foo import useful_thing`
(which would also allow the functionality of:

```
import foo
foo.useful_thing
```

)
The file structures they provide in their question are:

```
$ tree -a ./foo_folder/
./foo_folder/
├── setup.py
├── README.rst
├── ...etc...
└── foo.py

0 directories, 4 files
```

and

```
$ tree -a ./foo_folder/
./foo_folder/
├── setup.py
├── README.rst
├── ...etc...
└── foo
    ├── module.py
    └── __init__.py

2 directories, 4 files
```

where `useful_thing` is defined in `module.py` and the contents of `__init__.py` would be:

```
from foo.module import useful_thing
```

This question and the answer:
https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/a/243045
(which says: use whichever works for you)
Provides a couple of example packages that are distributions of just one module. Specifically https://pypi.org/project/six/ which I used the structure to get my tool working as both a CLI tool and import.

This was the final result:

```
$ tree ./mytool/
./mytool/
├── mytool.egg-info
│   ├── dependency_links.txt
│   ├── entry_points.txt
│   ├── PKG-INFO
│   ├── requires.txt
│   ├── SOURCES.txt
│   └── top_level.txt
├── mytool_helper.py
├── mytool.py
└── setup.py

1 directory, 9 files
```

contents of `setup.py`:

```
"""
The setup module for mytool
"""

# To use a consistent encoding
from os import path

# Always prefer setuptools over distutils
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

import mytool # NOTE: this is importing the file

version = '0.0.2'

here = path.abspath(path.dirname(__file__)) # NOTE: This is leftover, I should probably prune

setup(
    name='mytool',
    version=version,

    description='Do stuff with a string',


    #packages=find_packages(), # NOTE: I commented this because I don't think it's technically a "package" anymore just a moduel
    py_modules=['mytool'],

    classifiers=[
        'Programming Language :: Python :: 3'
    ],
    install_requires=[
        'argparse',
        'pyyaml'
    ],
    extras_require={
    },
    entry_points={
        'console_scripts': [
            'mytool=mytool:main'  # NOTE: have to change this here because the file structure is different
        ]
    }
)
```

contents of mytool.py (simplified):

```
import json
import argparse

from mytool_helper import HelperClass # NOTE:You just import the helper file/module directly here rather than as a module as part of a package.

# various string manipulation functions
#...

def process_string(in_string):
    result = HelperClass.parse_string(in_string)
    #  Do stuff with string
    return result.to_string()


def main():
    # This just gets the input via argparse
    input_string = _get_input_string()
    result_string = process_string(input_string)
    print(json.dumps(result_string, indent=4, default=str))


if __name__ == "__main__":
  main()
```

Which allows for it to be installed in an editable manner with pip:
`pip install -e /home/user/project/mytool/`

- The CLI usage: `mytool string_to_process`
- In script:

```
import mytool
result = mytool.process_string("string_to_process")
```

I may have still confused terms here, but this should help someone with structure and file contents.
I should probably also explain some of the other pieces, or provide links, for things like how to make the CLI part of the tool (https://setuptools.pypa.io/en/latest/userguide/entry_point.html)